# Testing and decrementing in an atomic operation?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have just traced down an annoying bug which is basicly a race condition. For the sake of the argument lets assume a very simple document structure like `{ _id : 'XXX', amount : 100 }`.

Hundreds of these these documents exist inside a collection and are accessed by multiple writers which effectively try to lower the amount by any value but never below 0. Currently this is done with two queries:

- The first query determines the current amount.
- The second query is only fired if the amount is greater then the value to subtract and decrements the current amount.

This is of course prone to result in a mess when multiple threads do this simultaneously. But is there a way to do this in an atomic operation? I couldn't find anything like a `test-and-set` operation in the docs.

If its relevant: The code running these operations is serverside JavaScript running with multiple Node.js instances and the `mongodb` npm package.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Qualify the update to only update the doc if `amount` is greater than 0:

```
db.coll.update({_id: 'XXX', amount: {$gt: 0}}, {$inc: {amount: -1}})
```

Comment: Whoops ... That was sort of too obvious ... Will accept as soon as SO allows me to.

Answer (score 0):

Like or Undo Like, where operator = 1 or -1

```
   const post = await Post.findOneAndUpdate(
      {
        _id: req.params.id,
        likes: operator == 1 ? { $gte: 0 } : { $gt: 0 },
      },
      {
        $inc: {
          likes: operator,
        },
      },
      {
        new: true,
      }
    );
```