# MongoDB have an integer always be positive

Tags: mongodb

Is it possible to enforce a field and have mongoDB always have a positive value for an integer field? It would be ideal if increment wouldn't make a number negative.

Comment: MongoDB doesn't have any schema to restrict. Are you using NodeJS ? If so mongoose will do that.

Comment: @SivaSankar Nope, Im using ReactiveMongo with a Play 2.3 server

Comment: In regards to `$inc`, see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14463189/testing-and-decrementing-in-an-atomic-operation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't restrict the data input/output on MongoDB, You need to do this in your program/code

Comment: From 3.2 version, you have [Document Validation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document-validation/) that provides the capability to validate documents during updates and insertions.